# How to set start of sequence using expression

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to set the `START` value of a sequence using a `SELECT` statement:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE sec_dogs 
OWNED BY dogs.dog_id 
START (SELECT MAX(dog_id) FROM dogs);
```

But I'm getting following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: ... BY dogs.dog_id START (SELECT MA...
                                 ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 97
```

I have tried using `DECLARE/BEGIN` and `WITH AS` but didnt work.
It works perfectly if I use an integer such as `100` instead of the `SELECT` statemenent.

Comment: You need to use `setval()` after creating the sequence

Comment: Try `select setval('sec_dogs', select max(dog_id) from dogs)` (as per dupe)

Comment: Tried using `SELECT setval('sec_dogs', SELECT MAX(dog_id) FROM dogs, true);` and returns an error: syntax error at or near "SELECT"

Comment: Solved, I needed to cast the value:
`select setval('sec_dogs',  (SELECT CAST((SELECT MAX(dog_id) FROM dogs) AS INTEGER)));`